# CSS: How can i get rid of the Input box spacing problem?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website with a login screen and i have the problem that the login button is 10px smaller than the Username and Password input boxes.

[image: website]

I've styled all on 90% size, but because I've added 10px left padding on the Input boxes, so the placeholder text has a spacing to the border. If I added the padding only to the placeholder, then I have the problem that as soon as i type something into the box the padding goes away.
So how can I shift the placeholder 10px to the right and also the text which i type into it?

Problem Input box greater size:

[image]

Problem no spacing:

[image]

```css
login ul {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.login {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

login li input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}

login li input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #1ED760;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120%;
}

.username-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
}

.username-box::placeholder {
  color: #1ED760;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.password-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
}

.password-box::placeholder {
  color: #1ED760;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.login-btn {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<login class="login">
  <ul>
    <li><input class="username-box" type="text" placeholder="Username"></li>
    <li><input class="password-box" type="text" placeholder="Password"></li>
    <li><button width="" class="login-btn" type="submit"><div class="login-btn.text">Login</div></button></li>
  </ul>
</login>
```

Comment: Did you try `padding`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to your inputs. That way, the `padding` you add will not increase the inputs width, as width and height properties will include the content, **padding**, and border.

To know more about `box-sizing` property, see [box-sizing - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Obs: I added some background color to your inputs to make their width visible.

```css
login ul {
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.login {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

login li input {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-color: black;
}

login li input[type="text"] {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #1ED760;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 120%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.username-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
}

.username-box::placeholder {
  color: #1ED760;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.password-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
}

.password-box::placeholder {
  color: #1ED760;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.login-btn {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<login class="login">
  <ul>
    <li><input class="username-box" type="text" placeholder="Username"></li>
    <li><input class="password-box" type="text" placeholder="Password"></li>
    <li><button width="" class="login-btn" type="submit"><div class="login-btn.text">Login</div></button></li>
  </ul>
</login>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Hope adding this CSS code will solve your problem.Read more on box-sizing property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)